# Playing portion of an audio file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

Does anyone knows how to play a portion of a sound file on the iPhone?
Using the SDK, or any other library (Cocos Desnhion...).

I know how to play an entire sound, but not an exact portion of it (eg. from 2,5ms to 6ms).

Thanks!

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer has a currentTime property. Set it to start playing the file at a specific time  mark and then watch its progress to stop playing when it reaches a desired mark.